# get href of div from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that essentially looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="link"></a>
    <div class="text"> Some plain text </div>
</div>
```

Now I append a href to `div.text` like this:

```
$('div.text').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<a class="append" href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"></a>');
});​
```

The problem is that I need to get the href from `a.link`. How do I go one level up to that href? Obviously  `'this'` doesn't work. I also cant call it by class name since there are lots of `a.link` and they are also dynamically created. I also cant use 'parent' or 'parents', for some reason it doesn't work in my script.

Comment: jQuery has many different methods to traverse the DOM: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/.

Comment: *"How do I go one level up to that href? ... I also cant use 'parent' or 'parents', for some reason it doesn't work..."* Perhaps if your HTML was indented more cleanly, you'd see that the `<a>` isn't a parent.

Comment: Can someone fill me in on the negative votes. They seem kinda ridiculous

Comment: @Youss - Judging by the fact there's also a "too localized" close vote on the question, I think the downvotes are likely to be because it could have been answered by a quick read through the jQuery API. However, I tend to disagree with that train of thought (hence me answering you anyway). It's a pretty simple question (no offence intended) which took me a few seconds to answer. My answer helps you out, and that's why I participate on this site. Sorry, that's a bit of rant at the site in general, but this kind of thing seems to be more and more of an issue these days.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: With all due respect, I don't think votes are used to judge how easy a question is to answer. The first thing I see when I hover the down arrow is *"This question does not show any research effort;"*

Comment: Talking about a quick read through..

Comment: @user1689607 - No, I agree, that's not what I was intending that to come across as. The OP in this case has mentioned some methods they've tried to use which have failed, which does show *some* research effort. Sure there could have been more (see my comment on my own answer), but I'm here to help people solve their problems and it really doesn't bother me if an OP hasn't exhausted all other lines of enquiry before posting on SO (I know the majority of users here have the opposite view though). Question comments are not the place for this discussion though.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Fair 'nuff. :)

Comment: Read every word, and quoted the key points.

Comment: @James Allardice Thanks for explaining. When I look at it know it does seem simple. I think I couldnt solve it because my real code 'looks' very complex. I should have written it down like in my question above, it would have made more sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.parent()` won't work because the `a` element is a *sibling*, not a parent. You can use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead:

```
$(this).append('<a class="append" href="' + $(this).prev().attr('href') + '"></a>');
```

The `.prev()` method will return the immediately preceding element. If your markup was to change, you could also use [`.prevAll(".link")`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/), or [`.siblings(".link")`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: I did not know about 'prev' 'prevall' and 'siblings'. Thank you very much:)

Comment: @Youss - You're welcome, glad I could help :) As was alluded to by Felix in the comments on your question, it's a good idea to spend some time browsing the jQuery API. There are usually numerous methods to solve every DOM traversal problem you could imagine!